# AngularJS typeahead not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typeahead.js

I am using `typeahead` on an `input` element as follows:

```
<form ng-controller = "emailViewController">
   <input type="text" placeholder="To" ng-model = "select" typeahead = "toPerson for toPerson in to | filter:$viewValue" style="width:95%;"><br />
   <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" style="width:95%;"><br />
   <textarea style="width:95%;" rows="10"></textarea>
</form>
```

This is the `emailViewController`, which is making a call to `fetchDataService` to get the `emails` data.

```
fetchDataService.getContent(url)
   .then(function(response){
      $scope.emails = response.data;
      $scope.to = [];

      angular.forEach($scope.emails, function(key, value) {
         $scope.to.push(key.to);
      })

      $scope.loadEmails('Primary');
});
```

I have trouble figuring out how to get `typeahead` to work.

**Update**

`typeahead` was not working because I wasn't referencing `ui.bootstrap` correctly. The following code works perfectly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Gmail App</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 50px;
        }
    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <script src="Vendor/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <script src="Vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="Vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Vendor/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.11.1/bloodhound.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="iisEmail">
<div class="container" ng-controller="mainController">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    Email <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Mail</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                    <li ng-click="loadView('settings')"><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
            <!-- split button -->
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                    <div class="checkbox" style="margin: 0;">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox"
                                   ng-click="selectAllEmail()"
                                   ng-model="checkAllEmail">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </button>

            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Refresh">
                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>   
            </button>
            <!-- Single button -->
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    More <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Mark all as read</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="text-center"><small class="text-muted">Select messages to see more actions</small></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <span class="text-muted"><b>1</b>–<b>50</b> of <b>277</b></span>
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block" role="button" ng-click="composeEmail()">COMPOSE</a>
            <hr/>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li class="" ng-repeat="item in leftMenu">
                    <a href="#"><span class="badge pull-right">{{item.emailCount}}</span> {{item.name}} </a>
                </li>
                <!--<li><a href="#">Starred</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Important</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sent Mail</a></li>
                <li>-->
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
            <!-- Nav tabs -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" ng-click="loadEmails('Primary')">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox">
                    </span>Primary</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" ng-click="loadEmails('Social')">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                    Social</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" ng-click="loadEmails('Promotions')">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tags"></span>
                    Promotions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus no-margin">
                    </span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Tab panes -->
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div ui-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close">×</button>
            <h3>Compose Email</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form ng-controller = "emailViewController">
                <input type="text" placeholder="To" ng-model="select" typeahead="toPerson for toPerson in to | filter:$viewValue" style="width:95%;"><br />
                <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" style="width:95%;"><br />
                <textarea style="width:95%;" rows="10"></textarea>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Send</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="app/main.js"></script>
<!--Services-->
<script src="app/services/commonApiService.js"></script>
<script src="app/services/fetchDataService.js"></script>
<script src="app/filters/emailFilter.js"></script>
<script src="app/controllers/mainController.js"></script>
<script src="app/controllers/settingsController.js"></script>
<script src="app/controllers/emailViewController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`main.js` - Module `iisEmail` is defined here.

```
var app = angular.module("iisEmail",['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
        var primary = {
            name:"primary",
            url:"/",
            templateUrl:"app/partials/emailView.html"
            //controller:"emailViewCtrl"
        };
        var settings ={
            name:"settings",
            url:"/",
            templateUrl:"app/partials/settings.html"
            //controller:"emailViewCtrl"
        };
        $stateProvider.state('default',primary);
        $stateProvider.state('settings',settings);
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should retrieve the values of select from `fetchDataService` call, thus your typeahead property needs to be like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="To" ng-model = "select" typeahead = "toPerson for toPerson in fetchDataService($viewValue)" style="width:95%;">
```

And `fetchDataService` should return values which will fulfill the options of select control.

```
fetchDataService.getContent(url)
   .then(function(response){
      //do your $scope manipulations as you wish but return your results
      return response.data;
});
```

You can check out the details of typeahead from the docs:
[Docs for typeahead of ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it did not work for me. Can you elaborate the `fetchDataService` part?

Comment: @Michelle for using typeahead asynchronously your function needs to return the data that you will use in the select control. In your case you retrieve data from the variable `to` which seems to be enough for your case. But if your data set grows you have to query your results from server in that case you can use typeahead like in my example.